# How can I print(to a printer) a string in django using a button click?

Tags: django, django-forms

For printing the string from the database, all I know is to generate a pdf and then render it on a button click.
I want to make all that happen(generating a pdf and rendering) on a single click of button. 
Is there a faster & efficient way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to just generate and render pdf in the same view. I have a pet project where I generate pdf tickets http://ticket4event.herokuapp.com/en/

View, which responsible for generating and returning pdf ticket:

```
def ticket(request, pk):
    """
    Show example of the ticket
    :param request:
    :return: response
    """

    t = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=pk)
    pdf_ticket = ticket_to_pdf(t.visitor, t.event)
    response = HttpResponse(pdf_ticket['content'], content_type=pdf_ticket['mimetype'])
    response['Content-Disposition'] = ('inline; filename=' + pdf_ticket['filename'])

    return response
```

Helper function for rendering pdf:

```
def ticket_to_pdf(visitor, event):
    """
    Render ticket to pdf 
    :param visitor:
    :param event:
    :return: dict with pdf and meta info
    """

    filename = 'ticket.pdf'
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current().domain
    site = '{scheme}://{host}'.format(scheme=config.SCHEME, host=current_site)
    url = pyqrcode.create(current_site + visitor.get_absolute_url())
    qr_code = url.png_as_base64_str(scale=5)
    ticket = render_to_string('pdf/ticket.html', {'visitor': visitor,
                                              'qr_code': qr_code,
                                              'event': event,
                                              'config': config})

    html = HTML(string=ticket, base_url=site)
    pdf = html.write_pdf()

    return {
        'filename': filename,
        'content': pdf,
        'mimetype': 'application/pdf',
    }
```